# Allow a RSU receive messages in Veins

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to implement a very simple scenery on Veins (OMNeT++ + SUMO) with just three vehicles and one unique fixed RSU, but I'm new in Veins and I'm not able to move very well, despite the tons of documents, FAQs and tutorials I've already read!

My start point is the default TraCI scenary demo, but here the vehicles send and receive, while the RSU just send in broadcast. I managed to fix manually my RSU (adding a `MapName.add.xml` file and import it from `MapName.sumo.cfg`, and later modifying `RSU.ned` and `omnetpp.ini`). So, at this point I can see my RSU on the simulation map, and the SUMO simulation end well. But for resolve my problem I need to allow RSU not only to send, but also to receive (I have to establish a V2I2V communication).

The copious material I found is sometimes similar to my goal, but dispersive and lacking, and none found any solution. How to edit this default scenery to reach this outcome? Would be extraordinary to have a complete and working code, or be driven by someone more experienced than me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial that comes with Veins 4a2 already includes an RSU that receives data. When it does, it changes its color to green. See [TraCIDemoRSU11p::onData](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc#L43) for how this is done.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you really **that** Christoph Sommer? Is a great honor to speak with you!
I had already guessed to work on `TraCIDemo11p.cc` and `TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc`, but I could not adapt the code for my necessity. When I consult the statistics, RSU don't receive packets. My final goal is allow two RSUs to communicate with each other: the vehicles can intercept the messages and forward to the second RSU. Conceptually is very easy but I have big difficults to translate in code. How can I use `TraCIDemoRSU11p::onData`? For now I'm happy just to make a RSU to receive from the vehicles.

Comment: Is the RSU turning green at event #960, as shown in the screenshot? If yes, the source code that reacts on packet reception was run.

Comment: I verified that RSUs receive. Now I need a second antenna on my car. In `Car.ned` I copied the connections block renaming `nic` with `nic2`, `appl` with `appl2` and `veinsradioIn` with `veinsradioIn2`. Now I have two antennas on my node (and they work!). But how can I decide who sends and who receives? In this way I just changed the topology of the network, but I can't handle the operating principle! I need to reach this scenario: node->node (first antenna) and node->RSU (second antenna).

Comment: I think that is a different question than the one in this topic. StackOverflow is building a repository of questions and good answers. This only works if exactly one question per post is asked/answered. Kindly create a new question instead

Comment: I'll do it. Sorry. :-)