# How can I simulate the two simple scenarios in Veins?

Tags: omnet++

I am a PhD student at INSA Lyon, France. I work on mobility in urban environments.

I installed Omnet ++ 4.6, Sumo 0.21.0 and  Veins 3.0 to simulate vehicle mobility.
In fact, I've never used Omnet ++ in my previous work. I read the existing tutorials of Omnet ++  in the website and now I want to start to simulate these two small scenarios:

1 Scenario: I want to have a set of mobile vehicles that exchange information among themselves

2nd scenario: I want to have a set of mobile vehicles and a set of fixed RSU that exchange information

What can I change in the existing example of  Veins to lead simulate these scenarios please?
Can you help me to do this please.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using Road Side Units (RSUs) in your simulation, you might want to base your work on Veins 4a2 instead. Its example simulation already includes an RSU participating in data exchange: as soon as a vehicle stops, it sends a message. Each vehicle and RSU that receives a message re-broadcasts one message per simulation. Each vehicle that receives a message computes a different route to avoid the road where the message originated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723714/4707703) for a screenshot of the resulting simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reponse Sir.