# RSU not receiving WSMs in Veins 4.5

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using the Veins 4.5 framework for a semester project. I am trying to observe the behavior of different functions in the sample codes given. For some reason, the RSU's `onWSM` function never gets called. I added a message (using the EV command) to print to the log whenever this function is called but the message is never logged. I tried the same thing in the vehicle's `onWSM` function and it works. I do not understand what the problem is here.

I searched Google and apparently other people have posted similar questions on different forums but have not received an answer (e.g. http://java.wekeepcoding.com/article/10429913/RSU+receiving+message+but+onWSM+method+not+executing+in+veins+4.5). There are answers regarding the same issue for a different version of Veins but the functions are now different in the version I am using (e.g. [Allow a RSU receive messages in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722038/allow-a-rsu-receive-messages-in-veins)).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is to look into the [handleLowerMsg](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L216) function inside BaseWaveApplLayer to see whether or not onWSM is actually getting called on arrival of a WSM for the RSU.

Comment: I added log messages in the `handleLowerMsg` function. In the log, the messages are only printed for the nodes (i.e. cars), not the RSU. For the nodes, the message only gets printed for the `bsm` part of the `if-else` conditions. I tried adding an `onBSM` function in the RSU application to see if that function will ever get called but it doesn't. Any other suggestions?